# NetBeans 7.0.1 refactor getters and setters

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 , when generating the entity class from database , the fields names are like the ones from the database. because of some issues i have to change the entity class filed names.

my question is how i can rename a field and that it's getters and setters will be changes also automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is old but under right click menu "Refactor->Rename" you have a a flag "Rename getters and setters". Check that flag and it will rename the getters and setters as well. If you click "Ctrl-R" the menu doesn't show up.

Answer (score -2):

You could just delete the old getters and setters, rename the fields, and then let NetBeans generate the getters and setters anew.

Comment: I know that.. i wanted to know if i can do it all together.